# How to calculate the coordinates of other two corners of an isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

I have an equilateral triangle with the knowns: coordinates of all the three corners and the circumcircle radius and center coordinates.

Now I want to change the angle of A ( increase or decrease) while holding the coordinates of A and the triangle always staying in the same circumcircle, and find the new coordinates of B and C which can be B1 and C1 as you can see in the following image : how is it possible to do ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that the circle is centered at the origin, for simplicity (origin is $O$ and radius is $R$). Then, we can find the $x$-coordinate of the point $B$. Notice that the triangle $AOB$ is an isosceles triangle.

Draw a horizontal line through $B$ and let's say that the point where this line crosses $x=0$, let's call that point $D$. Due to the isosceles triangle, the angle $DOB$ is twice that of the angle $OAB$, or
$$
DOB =2 \times OAB =  2 \times \frac{\alpha}{2} = \alpha
$$
($\alpha$ is the variable angle "A0" in your picture.) Now the distance from $D$ to $B$ can be solved with trigonometry:
$$
\sin{DOB} = \frac{DB}{R} \Rightarrow DB =  R\sin{\alpha}
$$
Therefore, the $x$-coordinate of the point $B$ is just 
$$
x_B = R\sin{\alpha}
$$
The $y$-coordinate is easy to solve from the definition of a circle:
$$
x_B^2 + y_B^2 = R^2 \Rightarrow y_B = \sqrt{R^2 - \left(R\sin{\alpha}\right)^2} = R \sqrt{1- \sin^2{\alpha}}
$$

I think we're done here.

Comment: thank you very much, and what if the circle center displaces ? how would I generalize the formula ?

Comment: Then you just move the whole thing by the amount of displacement $(x_O, y_O)$. So for example point $B$ moves from
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_B \\ y_B
\end{array}
\right)
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
R\sin{\alpha} \\ R \sqrt{1- \sin^2{\alpha}}
\end{array}
\right)
\qquad \rightarrow \qquad 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_B \\ y_B
\end{array}
\right)
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_O \\ y_O
\end{array}
\right) + 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
R\sin{\alpha} \\ R \sqrt{1- \sin^2{\alpha}}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Feel free to upvote/mark as accepted my answer, if you feel like it answered your question.

Comment: Sure ! thank you for the excellent answer. Usually we have to wait 24hrs or so, but I think your answer was perfect

Comment: I think there is a problem, DOB is not an angle equal to A0

Comment: Why do you say so? From the geometry, I'm quite convinced that it follows from the properties of an isosceles triangle.

Comment: because the point A should always remain on the perimeter. but O is the circle center, D and B are on perimeter. so ABC is a  triangle and DOB remains inside it

Comment: I have added an image to explain my point. ABC always remains on perimeter, DOB has one point on the center of the circle

Comment: So it's something like this, right? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vdszr0tcgx

Comment: well, what you have formulated looks like that , What I intended, was to always keep all the three points of the triangle on the circle perimeter, and by increasing the angle A0, determine the coordinates of the B and C

Comment: I repeat my question: Why do you suspect that angle $DOB$ is not equal to $AO$?

Comment: ok I think I was misunderstanding. so doesthis ratio hold even if the points B and C go under the y axis, in case center is always at (0,0)?

Comment: Yes, because it's an isosceles triangle. So I still believe that my answer is correct and usable.

Comment: thank you, in your formulas is x the horizontal or vertical axis ?

Comment: Like in the vast majority of coordinate conventions, $x$ is the horizontal axis.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was making a drawing mistake. The formulas are 100% accurate ! thank you !